# Web caching with SSL connection and dynamic contents

Tags: ssl, squid, varnish, cache

I have some questions about web-caching systems.

If I use systems like Squid, Varnish as reverse-proxy in front of my architetture:

- Is possible to have SSL connection from user to my proxy and SSL connection from my proxy to my web server? In this situation, if all my connection uses SSL...is possible to use caching system?
- If I have more dynamic pages (for example with the name of the users at the top of the page) is possible to use the web caching? Usually, web caching with Squid, Varnish is also used on only static content or also for dynamic content?

Answer (score 2):

1. Can I proxy an ssl connection to an ssl backend: yes
2. Dynamic content cannot be cached via traditional means without considerable modifications. Usually only static content (Content that does not change based on user state) is cached.

Answer (score 2):

Never used Squid, so my answer is limited to Varnish.

- Varnish doesn't understand SSL so you would have to use some king os SSL terminator in front of Varnish (like latest HAproxy, stud, stunnel or so) and again another layer between Varnish and backend servers is HTTPS to the backend is a requirement. [1]
- You can use Varnish advanced methods like ESI includes to perform such an advanced dynamic caching, but that won't be trivial to implement. [2]

[1] https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/phk/ssl.html

[2] https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/users-guide/esi.html?highlight=esi